# Field extension of degree two is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I want to show that each extension of degree $2$ is normal.

I have done the following:

Let $K/F$ the field extension with $[F:K]=2$.

Let $a\in K\setminus F$. Then we have that $F\leq F(a)\leq K$.

We have that $[K:F]=2\Rightarrow [K:F(a)][F(a):F]=2$.

There are the following possibilities:

1. $[K:F(a)]=1$ and $[F(a):F]=2$ 
   In this case we have that $K=F(a)$ and $\deg m(a,F)=2$. 
   In $K$, since $a\in K$, we have that $m(a,F)=(x-a)g(x)$, with $\deg g(x)=1$. Since $g$ is a linear polynomial of $K[x]$ , so it is of the form $x-c$, so its root $c$ must belong to $K$. 
   That means that $m(a,K)$ splits in $K$, i.e., all the roots are in $K$. Does this mean then that all the irreducible polynomials that have one root in $K$, have all the roots in $K$ ? Or how do we conclude then that the extension $K/F$ is normal ?
2. $[K:F(a)]=2$ and $[F(a):F]=1$ 
   In this case we have that $F=F(a)$, and so $a\in F$, a contradiction.

Is this correct? Could I improve something?

Comment: This is basically right, but normality means that if an irreducible polynomial $f \in F[x]$ has a root in $K$, then all of the roots of $f$ lie in $K$. So apply your argument directly to prove this fact.

Comment: Normality means that **all** the irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ satisfy this property, or not? Knowing that the minimal polynomial satisfy this property, how can we conclude that all the irreducible polynomials have all the roots in $K$ ? @AshwinIyengar

Comment: Does it maybe hold that all the polynomials other than the $m(a,F)$ are multiples of $m(a,F)$ and so not irreducible, because of the following? We are looking the polynomials in $F[x]$ that have roots in $F[a]$. So, either the polynomials have roots in $F$ and then they are not irreducible in $F[x]$ or they have roots in $F[a]$, i.e., they have as root an expression of $a$. If they have as a root $a$, then they are a multiple of $m(a,F)$. Can it be that they have an other polynomial expression of $a$ as a root, for example $a^2$ ?  @AshwinIyengar

Comment: A theorem says that $L/K$ is normal (and finite) if only if $L$ is the splitting field of some polynomial in $K[x]$.

Comment: In my notes there is the following definition: 
$$$$ 
$E/F$ normal $\Leftrightarrow$ each irreducible of $F[x]$ that has a root in $E$, has all its roots in $E$ (it splits in E) 
$$$$ 
$E/F$ normal $\Leftrightarrow$ each irreducible of $F[x]$ has either no root in $E$ or it splits in $E$ $$$$ @Charter

Comment: If an irreducible polynomial (assume it's monic by dividing out by the leading coefficient) $f \in F[x]$ has a root $\alpha \in K$, then $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (why?). Then follow your argument. Alternatively, consider Charter's response.

Comment: Do we have that if an irreducible polynomial $f\in F[x]$ has a root $a\in K$, then $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$, because otherwise we there would be a polynomial with smaller degree than $f$ that has the root $a$. Is this not possible? @AshwinIyengar

Comment: Up to scaling, yes

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-) @AshwinIyengar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of your solution is ok but there are little mistakes. First of all, it's $[K:F]=2$ and not $[F:K]=2$. Now you have $\deg m(a,F)=2$, and since $a$ is a root of $m(a, F)$ we can write in $K$: $m(a, F)=(x-a)g(x)$, using that $\deg m(a, F)=2$ we get $\deg g(x)=1$, so $g(x)$ has a root $c\in K$. This means that $m(a, F)\in F[x]$ splits in $K$, so by theorem that I wrote in the commentaries we have that $K/F$ is normal.

Alternatively, you can use the well-known fact that if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $|G:H|=2$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and then apply the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: So, is the statement of my notes that every irreducible polynomial must have either all the roots or no root $K$, wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar yeah, it's correct, but I prefer to define a normal extension $E/F$ to be an extension where "each irreducible of $F[x]$ that has a root in $E$, has all its roots in $E$." Using this definition is easy to prove the theorem that I used in my answer.

Comment: Ah ok... How could we prove it? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: With "some polynomials" of your Theorem are the ones meant that have a Root in E?

Comment: It's not "some polynomials" but just "one polynomial", and yes, that polynomial splits in $E$. For a proof of the theorem you can check chapter 9, section 9.2 of Stewart's book "Galois Theory" (3rd edition).